# How to use a single Firestore instance throughout an android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a single Firestore instance throughout an app because with Firebase's cold start the first query or the first data to be fetched takes sometime(like 2000ms-3000ms). I tried having Firestore object as static in a class that extends Application but it shows a Lint warning "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak". I don't know where to go from here. Please help me.

Comment: the FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() does particularly that, when you use .getInstance() it will get the same instance through the whole app

Comment: As @GastónSaillén specified in his comment, `getInstance()` it's a singleton, it will always return a single instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#public-static-firebasedatabase-getinstance) will get you an unique instance throught your whole app, when you use

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
```

or

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
```

It will **not** create another instance if you are creating them in different classes, instead, it will reuse the same one over and over again.

You can also see the implementation by `ctrl + click` on the method in your IDE

```
@NonNull
  public static FirebaseFirestore getInstance() {
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
    if (app == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("You must call FirebaseApp.initializeApp first.");
    } else {
      return getInstance(app, "(default)");
    }
  }




@NonNull
  public static FirebaseApp getInstance() {
    synchronized(LOCK) {
      FirebaseApp defaultApp = (FirebaseApp)INSTANCES.get("[DEFAULT]");
      if (defaultApp == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process " + ProcessUtils.getMyProcessName() + ". Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.");
      } else {
        return defaultApp;
      }
    }
  }
```